# Copy value from an input to clipboard by clicking on another button-type-input using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to copy the value of a `text-type-input` to the clipboard by clicking on another `button-type-input`. Initially, I wanted even the `text-type-input` to be a `button-type-input`, but was unable to find a method to copy the value of a `button-type-input` to the clipboard.

The code can be found out at https://jsfiddle.net/aQwus/t6t69ppb/2/

Right now, the value doesn't get copied. Please suggest a way to do so, and a way to copy the value of a `button-type-input` to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Trying to copy the value of a hidden input is troubling here, so first unhide it**

Just need to change the order of the lines of the code. Write `id1.style.display = "block";` before the copying commands.

```js
var id1 = document.getElementById('id1');
var id2 = document.getElementById('id2');

id2.onclick = function() {
  
    id1.style.display = "block";
  
    //copying the value to clipboard
    id1.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
  
    id2.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<input id="id1" type="text" value="text text text!" style="display:none">
<input id="id2" type="button" value="Copy text">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple, just listen to the click event of the button, using element.addEventListener function.**

```js
function copyTextToClipboard() {

  var id1 = document.querySelector('#id1');

  //copying the value to clipboard
  id1.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");

  alert("Copied");

}

var id2 = document.querySelector('#id2');

id2.addEventListener("click", copyTextToClipboard);
```

```html
<input id="id1" type="text" value="text text text!">
<input id="id2" type="button" value="Copy text">
```

**Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6t69ppb/4/).**

Comment: you just assigned a click event on the whole window. So whenever you click anywhere in the window this callback will trigger. This was clearly not what op asked.

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan sorry small mistake, fixed it.

Comment: I tried the code in `JSFiddle` but it isn't working. Even though the code works in the `code snippet`. Can you please send a `JSFiddle` link with the code

Comment: The code works fine till the moment you apply `style = "display:none;"` for the `text-type-input`. This is the problem. My code also works fine for normal parameters but doesn't when the `text-type-input` is hidden. Please help me with this. If you may, fiddle with my JS link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
//or document.getElementById('id_form')

var str = JSON.stringify(formData);
str.select();
document.execCommand("Copy");
```

Comment: are you trying to create a new object?

Comment: I forgot to convert object to json. I have updated my answer